# .net get all directory from parent URI

Tags: c#, .net, uri

I want to get sub directory list from parent URI, how I can read

For example-

I have parent URI - www.abc.com

here I want to read its all sub directory like

```
1. www.abc.com/xyz/..
2. www.abc.com/xyz1/..
3. www.abc.com/xyz3/..
```

I have tried to read URI as below -

`var path = new Uri("www.abc.com");`

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is something like that

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The folder structure of a web server is private. All you can do is gleam information from what is publicly available. So you could crawl the site and it's links and build up a picture of it's folder structure. You could also try requesting www.abc.com/robots.txt which is used to tell search engines which things to index. You might get lucky and find that robots.txt contains a lot of information about it's sub folders. For example, look at the bbc.com robots.txt file http://www.bbc.com/robots.txt